# which is faster spark.sql or df.filter("").select("") . using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table that is a df which also has a view created with

```
table.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
```

and the query is

```
spark.sql("SELECT column1 from TABLE where column2 = 'VALUE'")
```

i want to rewrite the query as

```
TABLE.filter(TABLE("column2") === "value").select(col("column1"))
```

so which query is much faster the normal spark.sql or with filter and select ? when using large datasets.

Comment: Expecting an _"exact answer \[on\] performance"_ (as you state in a comment below) is plain silly. Performance is very sensitive to initial conditions -- which version of Spark? On which OS, hardware, Java version? How do you allocate the executors, statically/dynamically, large/small, scattered on multiple nodes or colocated on a few big bare-metal nodes? How did you tweak the 500+ undocumented Spark properties that make a difference at scale? And also Hadoop property if applicable, JVM garbage collector params? And about the dataset - size, types, cardinality/skew of the key columns if any?

Comment: Yes i know that there are several parameters that depend on the performance but iam expecting a genetic solution and which is used by most of the developers as making changes to properties should have the correct code implementation as well, just wanted to know the best practices as the same can be done in two different ways

Comment: I never understand these "I have two pieces of code, which one is faster" questions. It's easy: run both of them, the one that takes less time is faster!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on your use case just try both of them which works fast is the best suit for you !

I would recommend you to use

```
1.spark.time(df.filter(“”).select(“”)) 

2.spark.time(spark.sql(""))
```

you can print out the time and use the one which takes the least time to execute in your code to run it faster.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. simple and clean ! @Jack

Comment: I would like to at least point out for future readers that this code will not effectively *execute* the queries.

Answer (score 9):

I assume that if their physical execution plan is exactly the same, performance will be the same as well. So let's do a test, on Spark 2.2.0:

```
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> case class Record(column1: String, column2: String)
defined class Record

scala> val table = List(Record("foo", "value"), Record("bar", "notvalue")).toDF
table: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column1: string, column2: string]

scala> table.createOrReplaceTempView("table")

scala> val a = spark.sql("SELECT column1 from TABLE where column2 = 'value'")
a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column1: string]

scala> val b = table.filter(table("column2") === "value").select(col("column1")) 
b: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column1: string]

scala> a.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [column1#41]
+- *Filter (isnotnull(column2#42) && (column2#42 = value))
   +- LocalTableScan [column1#41, column2#42]

scala> b.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [column1#41]
+- *Filter (isnotnull(column2#42) && (column2#42 = value))
   +- LocalTableScan [column1#41, column2#42]
```

Looks like there's no difference at all...

Comment: This is the cleanest and best answer !

Answer (score 4):

I may be wrong, but it is exactly the same. Spark is gonna read both codes, interpret it via Catalyst and generate RDD code through Tungsten optimization.

The main change is the ease of coding and debugging. With spark.sql, you won't have any infos at compile time about errors or type mistakes...

And using .filter, .select is much easier to indent, to read, etc...

TLDR : Performance Wise = the same / Coding wise = spark.sql so much worse

Comment: Thanks for the info, but still looking forward for someone to give me an exact answer as performance is the key for me.

Comment: _"With spark.sql, you won't have any infos at compile time about errors or type mistakes"_ >  ?!?  you can just run that SQL in `spark-shell`, even in Hive... And SQL allows a lot more concision than the scala boilerplate verbose stuff, in my opinion.

Comment: Filtering on primitive data types (e.g. `int`) is reported to be marginally less efficient with scala API that imposes "boxing" the value with an object. The SQL parser can short-circuit that (same Catalyst core found in Drill, recent Hive, etc.)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter so you say writing the sql query is much better thank using filters ?

Comment: With spark.sql you have more possibilities. e.g. nested correlated sub queries. The answer is correct.

Comment: @sundeep, note the _"in my opinion"_ disclaimer. Also, SQL has been there for decades and is understood by many people in the field, while Scala is recent and may get out of fashion in the next 5 years, so SQL is a solid choice if you need to hand over your code to someone else. Parole d'ingénieur ;-)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Merci pour toutes ces infos !

Comment: You're working with big distributed data. One or two boxed integers in your driver program probably aren't going to make any measurable difference.