# PySpark filter DataFrame where values in a column do not exist in another DataFrame column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I don't understand why this isn't working in PySpark...

I'm trying to split the data into an `approved` DataFrame and a `rejected` DataFrame based on column values. So `rejected` looks at the `language` column values in `approved` and only returns rows where the `language` does not exist in the `approved` DataFrame's `language` column:

```py
# Data
columns = ["language", "users_count"]
data = [("Java", 20000), ("Python", 100000), ("Scala", 3000), ("C++", 10000), ("C#", 32195432), ("C", 238135), ("R", 134315), ("Ruby", 235), ("C", 1000), ("R", 2000), ("Ruby", 4000)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df.show()
# +--------+-----------+
# |language|users_count|
# +--------+-----------+
# |    Java|      20000|
# |  Python|     100000|
# |   Scala|       3000|
# |     C++|      10000|
# |      C#|   32195432|
# |       C|     238135|
# |       R|     134315|
# |    Ruby|        235|
# |       C|       1000|
# |       R|       2000|
# |    Ruby|       4000|
# +--------+-----------+

# Approved
is_approved = df.users_count > 10000
df_approved = df.filter(is_approved)
df_approved.show()
# +--------+-----------+
# |language|users_count|
# +--------+-----------+
# |    Java|      20000|
# |  Python|     100000|
# |      C#|   32195432|
# |       C|     238135|
# |       R|     134315|
# +--------+-----------+

# Rejected
is_not_approved = ~df.language.isin(df_approved.language)
df_rejected = df.filter(is_not_approved)
df_rejected.show()
# +--------+-----------+
# |language|users_count|
# +--------+-----------+
# +--------+-----------+

# Also tried
df.filter( ~df.language.contains(df_approved.language) ).show()
# +--------+-----------+
# |language|users_count|
# +--------+-----------+
# +--------+-----------+
```

So that doesn't make any sense - why is `df_rejected` empty?

**Expected outcomes using other approaches:**

SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM df
WHERE language NOT IN ( SELECT language FROM df_approved )
```

Python:

```py
data_approved = []
for language, users_count in data:
    if users_count > 10000:
        data_approved.append((language, users_count))

data_rejected = []
for language, users_count in data:
    if language not in [row[0] for row in data_approved]:
        data_rejected.append((language, users_count))

print(data_approved)
print(data_rejected)
# [('Java', 20000), ('Python', 100000), ('C#', 32195432), ('C', 238135), ('R', 134315)]
# [('Scala', 3000), ('C++', 10000), ('Ruby', 235), ('Ruby', 4000)]
```

Why is PySpark not filtering as expected?

Comment: Have you tried `!` instead of the `~`?

Comment: Note that there are duplicate `C` values in the data

Comment: @Mortz `!` doesn't work

Comment: @BrendanA yes that was intentional

Comment: Edited answer to accommodate duplicates!

Answer (score 1):

Try to:

```
df.subtract(df_approved).show()
                                                                                    
+--------+-----------+
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|       R|       2000|
|    Ruby|       4000|
|   Scala|       3000|
|       C|       1000|
|     C++|      10000|
|    Ruby|        235|
+--------+-----------+
```

UPD:
If you want to proceed with existing code without duplicates use python list instead of `Column` spark object.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
column_list= df_approved.select(f.collect_list('language')).first()[0]
                                                                                  
# output ['Java', 'Python', 'C#', 'C', 'R']
is_not_approved = ~df.language.isin(column_list)
df_rejected = df.filter(is_not_approved)
df_rejected.show()
                                                                                
+--------+-----------+
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|   Scala|       3000|
|     C++|      10000|
|    Ruby|        235|
|    Ruby|       4000|
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: This still contains languages that are in `is_approved` i.e. values `C` and `R` I'm trying to get rid of all `language`s in `df_rejected` that are in `df_approved`

Comment: @AK91 Ok, now I got the point. Your problem is that you should provide list of columns and not the `Column` spark object

Comment: @AK91 please review update

Comment: Wouldn't this be less performant than the SQL way? i.e. `spark.sql("...NOT EXISTS (...)")`

Comment: @AK91 speaking about which way is better you can refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52216480/which-is-faster-spark-sql-or-df-filter-select-using-scala.
I guess it doesn't matter which way to use. If you want to keep code use my way, and if you are ok with SQL use SQL and temporary view.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will want to use a `window` to select the maximum `user_count` of rows by `language`.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

columns = ["language", "users_count"]
data = [("Java", 20000), ("Python", 100000), ("Scala", 3000), ("C++", 10000), ("C#", 32195432), ("C", 238135), ("R", 134315), ("Ruby", 235), ("C", 1000), ("R", 2000), ("Ruby", 4000)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df = (df.withColumn('max_users_count', 
                     functions.max('users_count')
                      .over(w))
                      .where(functions.col('users_count') 
                        == functions.col('max_users_count'))
                         .drop('max_users_count'))
df.show()
+--------+-----------+
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|      C#|   32195432|
|     C++|      10000|
|       C|     238135|
|       R|     134315|
|   Scala|       3000|
|    Ruby|       4000|
|  Python|     100000|
|    Java|      20000|
+--------+-----------+
```

Then you can filter based on the specified condition.

```
is_approved = df.users_count > 10000
df_approved = df.filter(is_approved)
df_approved.show()
+--------+-----------+
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|    Java|      20000|
|  Python|     100000|
|      C#|   32195432|
|       C|     238135|
|       R|     134315|
+--------+-----------+
```

And then for the reverse of the condition, add the `~` symbol in the filter statement

```
is_not_approved = df.filter(~is_approved)
is_not_approved.show()
+--------+-----------+
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|   Scala|       3000|
|     C++|      10000|
|    Ruby|        235|
|       C|       1000|
|       R|       2000|
|    Ruby|       4000|
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: `is_not_approved` still contains languages that are in `is_approved` i.e. values `C` and `R` I'm trying to get rid of all `language`s in `df_rejected` that are in `df_approved`

Comment: Edited answer to do just that!

Answer (score 0):

Went the SQL route:

```py
columns = ["language", "users_count"]
data = [("Java", 20000), ("Python", 100000), ("Scala", 3000), ("C++", 10000), ("C#", 32195432), ("C", 238135), ("R", 134315), ("Ruby", 235), ("C", 1000), ("R", 2000), ("Ruby", 4000)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df_approved = df.filter(df.users_count > 10000)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
df_approved.createOrReplaceTempView("df_approved")

df_not_approved = spark.sql("""
    SELECT * FROM df WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM df_approved
        WHERE df.language = df_approved.language
        )
""")

df_not_approved.show()

# +--------+-----------+
# |language|users_count|
# +--------+-----------+
# |     C++|      10000|
# |    Ruby|        235|
# |    Ruby|       4000|
# |   Scala|       3000|
# +--------+-----------+
```